Closed Embedding into Projective Bundle Implies Projective Morphism
This is problem 17.3.A of Vakil's (late February 2024) Rising Sea.
A morphism $\pi \colon X \to Y$ is defined as projective when there is an isomorphism of $Y$-schemes $X \cong \underline{\operatorname{Proj}} \mathscr{S},$ for some quasicoherent sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_Y$-algebras $\mathscr{S}$, which is "finitely generated in degree one:" $\operatorname{Sym}^*\mathscr{S}_1 \to \mathscr{S}$ is surjective.
I'm supposed to show that $\pi$ is projective if and only if there exists finite type quasicoherent sheaf $\mathscr{S}_1$ on $Y$ with closed embedding $i \colon X \to \underline{\operatorname{Proj}} \operatorname{Sym}^* \mathscr{S}_1$
If $X$ is projective, this is simple to show. The other direction is giving me trouble. Given finite type quasicoherent sheaf of algebras $\mathscr{S}_1$, I think I ought to define
$$\mathscr{S} = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \mathscr{S}_1^{\otimes n},$$
which will be finitely generated in degree one. I know that this induces a closed embedding over $Y$ for relative proj:
$$\underline{\operatorname{Proj}} S \to \underline{\operatorname{Proj}} \operatorname{Sym}^* \mathscr{S}_1,$$
but I'm lost trying to show that $X \cong \underline{\operatorname{Proj}} \mathscr{S}$. Should I define a different sheaf of algebras? I'm not sure where else to go from here.
Any comments or suggestions would get great!

I'm sorry to tell you that the answer to this is put behind a starred item: see Exercise 15.7.J. I think I've reported this to Vakil and hopefully this will be fixed (for example, adding a hint) in the future.

Thanks for letting me know. I'll take a look at that exercise.
